# Help translating an Estee Lauder quotation to Latin

Tags: translation-check, style, english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to translate one quote from Estee Lauder, that goes as following:

> I have never dreamed about success. I worked for it.

Google translator returned this result:

> Numquam viderat elit. Et fecerunt pro ea.

Do you consider the last sentence to be grammatically and stylistically correct? If not, please suggest how you would re-phrase it, ideally with a bit of an explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not even close. Of the words, only *numquam* is the right word. As good as Google Translate is for other languages, it's not good at all for Latin.

A quick and dirty translation would go something like this:

> De prosperis numquam somniavi; immo eis laboravi.

You have some options for "success," but I think *prospera* works nicely in the phrase here. However, I should note it's post-Augustan in its usage. I don't know if that matters to you.

*Somniare* is your best bet with "to dream," and can even mean "to daydream," as in English. When you dream about a thing, rather than of the thing, Latin often puts that into *de* + the ablative, which is what I did there.

*Immo* here is working like a "nay":

> I did not...; nay, I did...

Finally, *laborare* means "to toil" or "to labor," and while you could have used a verb that meant "to strive for," to really emphasize the difficulty in "working for it," I chose this verb. Its object would go into the dative, so that's the simple *eis* (plural to go with *prospera*).

Comment: Your explanation is terrific! Just a subquestion though - google translated the second part of the sentence as "Indeed, it labored." Is there any way of saying skipping "Immo" and using a form closer to my original English quote? Thanks again

Comment: @LeoNapoleon Google is simply wrong there. The second part of CM's quote means "I worked for it"; *eō* is the object, the *-ī* in *laborāvī* specifies that "I" is the subject. *Immo* is an intensifier without a perfect English equivalent, making the contrast between the two parts more emphatic.

Comment: By 1200 **'somnium'** became **'sompnium'** and I would like the added emphasis of **sompniavi.**